# Child aura component attributes are getting undefined

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura

I am working on two aura components, I am passing attributes from parent to child, on parent component all values are present but when we are assigning to child component then they are getting undefined, Can anyone help in how to fix this issue.